# Fastest modular exponentiation

Tags: fastest-code

The challenge is to write code in any open source, available on linux, language of your choice to perform modular exponentiation. The input will be two randomly chosen 2048 bit positive integers numbers x and y and a 2048 bit prime z.  Here is a sample snippet of python to compare to.

```
def pow_mod(x, y, z):
    n = 1
    while y:
        if y & 1:
            n = n * x % z
        y >>= 1
        x = x * x % z
    return n
```

The code should accept a file with each of the three numbers on separate lines and output the result to standard out.  You may not use any libraries for modular exponentiation of course.

The code that runs the fastest on average over 100 runs on my computer wins.

For those who want really accurate timing, the best way may be for the timing code to actually be in the code you provide and for your code to simply repeat 100 times (without cheating :) ). This avoids any problems with start up overheads.

Comment: A good solution will probably use some addition-chain or addition-subtraction chain wizardry.  For example (I don't know if this particular approach is good, but...) http://cr.yp.to/ecdh/diffchain-20060219.pdf

Comment: Can you give us more info about your computer?

Comment: @Ray Ubuntu 64 bit 13.04 on amd fx8350 with 8GB RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### C++/asm

Runs in about 7ms on my laptop.  Less than a factor of 2 away from [GMP](http://gmplib.org/), which is heavily optimized for this task.

Uses [Montgomery reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery_reduction) to compute the modular reductions quickly.  Uses a python script to generate x86 assembly to do the 2048 bit ops (multiply, add, etc.) in great swathes of straightline code.

The code is about 270 lines, a bit big to paste in an answer box.  Download it [here](http://keithandkatie.com/modexp.zip).

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell

Though it's simple, it should be pretty fast if built with [GHC](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/distribution_packages):

```hs
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -O2 #-}
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

module Main where

import Data.Bits

seqI :: Integer -> Integer
seqI x = seq x x

seqB :: Bool -> Bool
seqB x = seq x x

getInteger :: IO Integer
getInteger = fmap (seqI . read) getLine

modExp' :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer
modExp' r b p m = let nextR = seqI $ mod (seqI $ r*b) m
                      nextB = seqI $ mod (seqI $ b*b) m
                      nextP = seqI $ shiftR  p 1
                      incl  = seqB $ testBit p 0
                      cont  = seqB $ nextP  /= 0
                  in  if incl
                         then if cont
                                 then modExp' nextR nextB nextP m
                                 else nextR
                         else if cont
                                 then modExp' r     nextB nextP m
                                 else r

modExp :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer
{-# INLINE modExp #-}
modExp !b !p !m = modExp' 1 b p m

main = do
          b <- getInteger
          p <- getInteger
          m <- getInteger
          print $ modExp b p m
```

#### Prime modulus optimization

If the modulus is guaranteed to be a prime, but the exponent might be greater than or equal to the modulus, the last line should be changed to:

```hs
          print $ modExp b (mod p (m - 1)) m
```

#### Handling multiple inputs

If you'd like it to handle multiple inputs per run, add `import System.IO` under the other `import` and the following two lines just under the `print` line:

```hs
          isDone <- isEOF
          if isDone then return () else main
```

#### Running

Once it's compiled, it can be run as `modexp < file`.

Comment: I compiled it with ghc -O2. It takes about 0.02 seconds but maybe it makes more sense to have the timing in the code itself.

Comment: It might have issues with startup time. I've added a section on how to get it to run, taking 3 lines at a time, all the way until the file ends. You can use `cat *.whatever | modexp` if you have the test inputs separated into many files.